# Hive query output to file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I run hive query by java code.
Example:

> "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 100"

How to export result to hdfs file.

Answer (score 70):

The following query will insert the results directly into HDFS:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path/to/output/dir' SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 100;
```

Comment: You could use the `printf` UDF (0.9) to format your input as you want, otherwise creating your own UDF might be an option.

Comment: @Charles - can you show or link to an example of how to use a printf UDF to format output?  Not obvious what to do here.

Comment: Thinks Charles is suggesting you use the printf UDF to format what you output, for example: insert overwrite directory '/path/to/output/dir' select printf("%s\t%s",arg1, arg2) from table where id > 100;

Answer (score 41):

This command will redirect the output to a text file of your choice:

```
$hive -e "select * from table where id > 10" > ~/sample_output.txt
```

Comment: how to overwrite the file if i want to run another select * command from a different table and write to same file ?

Comment: This will take ages for large tables, as it has to write it to stdout.

Comment: wouldn't that also write the progress to the output file? or is the progress written to stderr?

Comment: You can add -S to make it silent, meaning less noise in the file.

Comment: If your query is long, you can read the query from a file, like this: `$hive -f ~/query.hql > ~/out.txt`

Answer (score 29):

This will put the results in tab delimited file(s) under a directory:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/hadoop/YourTableDir'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 100;
```

Comment: Is there a way to spit out a header row?

Comment: I'm getting an error with this code: cannot recognize input near 'ROW' 'FORMAT' 'DELIMITED' in select clause

Comment: It seems like you have somehow a runoff line in your input; perhaps missing closing quotes. Try it in the console.

Comment: Please check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5672 and the fix is available from hive version 0.13

Answer (score 3):

I agree with tnguyen80's response. Please note that when there is a specific string value in query better to given entire query in double quotes.

For example:

```
$hive -e "select * from table where city = 'London' and id >=100" > /home/user/outputdirectory/city details.csv
```

Comment: is this going to write to HDFS or to the local filesystem - that looks like local to me, whereas the "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY" method  writes to HDFS

Answer (score 3):

The ideal way to do it will be using "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/pathtofile' select * from temp where id > 100" instead of "hive -e 'select * from...' > /filepath.txt"

Comment: Does it creates the file or file need to be created before?

Answer (score 3):

@sarath
how to overwrite the file if i want to run another select * command from a different table and write to same file ?

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/training/mydata/outputs' 
    SELECT expl , count(expl) as total
    FROM (
     SELECT explode(splits) as expl 
     FROM (
      SELECT split(words,' ') as splits 
      FROM wordcount
     ) t2
    ) t3 
    GROUP BY expl ;

This is an example to sarath's question

the above is a word count job stored in outputs file which is in local directory 
:)

Answer (score 3):

Two ways can store HQL query results:

1. Save into HDFS Location

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "HDFS Path" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
SELECT * FROM XXXX LIMIT 10;
```

2. Save to Local File

```sh
$hive  -e "select * from table_Name" > ~/sample_output.txt
$hive -e "select * from table where city = 'London' and id >=100" > /home/user/outputdirectory/city details.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an external table
2. Insert data into the table
3. Optional drop the table later, which wont delete that file since it is an external table

Example:

Creating external table to store the query results at *'/user/myName/projectA_additionaData/'*

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE additionaData
(
     ID INT,
     latitude STRING,
     longitude STRING
)
COMMENT 'Additional Data gathered by joining of the identified cities with latitude and longitude data' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE location '/user/myName/projectA_additionaData/';
```

Feeding the query results into the temp table

```
 insert into additionaData 
     Select T.ID, C.latitude, C.longitude 
     from TWITER  
     join CITY C on (T.location_name = C.location);
```

Dropping the temp table

```
drop table additionaData
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly save the file in HDFS, use the below command:

```
hive> insert overwrite  directory '/user/cloudera/Sample' row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile select * from table where id >100;
```

This will put the  contents in the folder /user/cloudera/Sample in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this line into Hive command line interface:

`insert overwrite directory '/data/test' row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile select * from testViewQuery;`

`testViewQuery` - some specific view

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

To set output directory and output file format and more, try the following:

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE [LOCAL] DIRECTORY directory1
[ROW FORMAT row_format] [STORED AS file_format] 
SELECT ... FROM ...
```

Example:

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path/to/output/dir'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS PARQUET
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 100;
```