# How to remove specific keys from Hive map type?

Tags: hive

I have a table with column whose type is `map<string,string>`. Now I have requirement where I want to remove specific key say "xyz" from this map and keep map as it is in table. If we just want to retrieve keys we can use `Lateral view` but I want to remove specific key xyz permanently.

How do we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hive (any hadoop ) does not support update on table data (document on hdfs).

So there is work around .

Use Lateral view explode and remove the key value from result set

[Str_to_map](https://www.qubole.com/resources/cheatsheet/hive-function-cheat-sheet/)  with group by create data in map format

you can have a view on above logic or  do [out put result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289846/hive-query-output-to-file) and create a table on top of this output files.

removing key example ([map explode example](http://linehrr.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-use-lateral-view-explode.html) )

```
        with result  as (select key1, value1  from test2 
              lateral view explode(item1) dummy1 as key1, value1

          select * from result   where key1 !='1'
```

Comment: Hi thanks I did not understand can you please give me example how do I remove specific key in a map and keep map in a table with removed specific keys.

Comment: OK thanks I am still confused will lateral view and explode remove specific key permanently from main table?

Comment: as i told u can not update data in hdfs  u have to create result set and do output that in csv  and use this file for new table..